# 35V LED power supply driving 11V LED - what happens to the "unused" power?

Tags: led-driver

I have a bunch of 10W lamps (like [this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/LED-Floodlight-Wash-Light-Garden-Lamp-Outdoor-Spotlights-10W-20W-110V-220V-OE-/111907606130)) with incorrect power adapters for the emitters - the drivers are meant for a 1x9 configuration (35V, ~300mA), LEDS are 3x3 (~11V, ~900mA).

I am fine with running them at 1/3 power, for now.

Question: what happens to the remaining 2/3 (~23V, 300mA)? Is it radiated off in the driver (and is that a concern, like a short circuit might)? Or does the driver deal with that differently?

Comment: Where's the link for the power supply?

Comment: Assuming the LED driver behaves as a current source, it will force a **current**. It will adjust the voltage so the required **current** flows. As these are usually switched regulators it will simply switch such that the **voltage** is lower. Think about what would happen if there was excess power and it would be dissipated in the driver. Would it not get very hot ? So no it is not dissipated in the driver. Same as when using a 12 V, 10 A power supply and loading it with 1 A. There is no remaining 9 A. The adapter only delivers 1 A.

Comment: @transistor It's a cheap waterproof power supply with aluminium and black resin outside. I do not have one at hand. [This one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/10W-20W-30W-50W-100W-High-Power-Waterproof-LED-Driver-Supply-LED-SMD-Chip-Bulb/371632020459) shows a range of 20-40V, whatever that means for this issue. Mine shows "34-35V".

Comment: @fakemoustache Thanks. Thing is, these kind of drivers usually show a RANGE of output voltages, like "6-12V, 900mA". The range is narrow on mine, and I do not understand what using an "unsupported" load will do.

Comment: And without knowing the design no-one can understand what will happen if you use the driver outside the specified range. With these cheap Chinese drivers my advice would be: don't use them outside their specified range.

Comment: "Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design." - doing so as concisely as I could (most people here presumably able to identify the situation without my putting up walls of speculation), I essentially asked which electrical design I was likely dealing with. Thanks for the answers. nrn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the range specified on the driver's output (e.g. "6-12V, 900mA"), the voltage will be adjusted to ensure a constant current. No power wasted.

Outside that range, behavior is undefined.

Thanks, FakeMoustache.

Comment: The only thing wasted is unused power potential in the LED supply which someone paid for in the first place but isn't using.